# How to add response into Json file obtained by Cucumber examples belonging to one scenario?

Tags: json, cucumber, compare

I have a scenario A
Scenario: Get data of main records
When I fetch data of all main records "BookName"  in tag symbol
Then I add main records to a test data records "BookName"  in tag symbol
Examples:
|BookName |
|A        |
|B        |
BookName in Then statement is used as a identifier

Write results to Json
\\\\\\\\
Scenario B
Scenario: Get data of main records
When I fetch data of all main records "BookName"  in tag symbol
Then I compare the data with actual data obtained from scenario A
Examples:
|BookName |
|A        |
|B        |

How do I write data into Json with different identifier and How do I compare data without using multiple scenarios for each bookname?

Answer (score 0):

You can either have one scenario  for each book with json in tables to compare. I am using my employee example but you get the point and tweak accordingly. First 3 steps are relatively simple, so not including

```
 Scenario: get employee
    Given an employee exist in the database with id "2"
    When  user retrieves employee info by id
    Then the status code for get employee is 200
    And response includes the following employee info
     | status               | success        |
    | data.employee_name    | Garrett Winters|
    | data.id               | 2              |
    | data.employee_age     | 63             |
```

For comparison I use

```
 @And("response includes the following employee info$")
public void employee_response_equals(Map<String, Object> ExpectedFields){
Map<String, Object> actualFields =  ExpectedFields.keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(expectedKey -> expectedKey, expectedKey -> jsonPathEvaluator.get(expectedKey).toString()));

assertThat(actualFields).containsAllEntriesOf(ExpectedFields); 
}
```

**OR**

You can  have your json in `example` table but you would have to use `@ParameterType` and parse . I am presenting my example here for `@ParameterType` but you can tweak it to enter your json instead of usernames etc. The point is to use [`@ParameterType`](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/configuration/?sbsearch=%40parametertype)

```
  Scenario Outline: Add a user using pojo class in scenario outline using @ParameterType
   
       Given I open the site "http://www.way2automation.com/angularjs-protractor/webtables/"
       When I add  user by passing <userInfo> to pojo class from scenario outline
       Then I see user <userInfo> added to the table
        Examples:
        |userInfo|
        |TestFirstName4,TestLastName4,testusername4,test98760,testuser4@testcompany4.com,7890-123-2233|
        |TestFirstName5,TestLastName5,testusername5,test67890,testuser5@testcompany5.com,456-789-1122|
```

step def

```
@ParameterType(".*?")
  public addUserPojo defineStringToPojo(String adduser) {
    List<String> usr = Arrays.asList(adduser.split(","));
   //use `usr` as needed
  }
```